# Change in order of integration.

Tags: integration

I have this equation, $$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{x}^{a}(x^2+y^2)dydx$$ and, I want to change the order of integration from $dydx$ to $dxdy$.$\text{ }y$ varies from $y=x \text{   to  }y=a$, and $x\text{  varies from }x=0 \text{ to } x=a$. When we change the order of integrals, I thought it should be

$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{y}^{a}(x^2+y^2)dxdy$$ but the actual result in the book says, it's.$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{a}^{y}(x^2+y^2)dxdy$$

am not getting why the limits of x should start from a and end at y instead of y to a, while $\int$ w.r.t dx?

-Kamal.

Comment: Try drawing the original region of integration. Rotate this by the line $y=x$, this should help you see the reparameterization

Comment: Try drawing a picture, and then this should be clear.

Comment: I think there is a typo. Surely the bounds of the inner integral in the last formula are $\int_0^y$ ($0$ to $y$), not $\int_a^y$ ($a$ to $y$)?

Comment: In the result in the book there is a typo: $\int_a^y$ must be $\int_0^y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, and the book is wrong. Since $x^2+y^2=y^2+x^2$ you can just interchange $x$ and $y$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^a\int_x^a(x^2+y^2)dydx=\int_0^a\int_y^a(y^2+x^2)dxdy=\int_0^a\int_y^a(x^2+y^2)dxdy.
\end{align*}
You can actually evaluate these integrals directly. While your idea gives $a^4/3$, the book's result would be $-a^4/3$.

Comment: This is a correct value but I suspect it the reason it comes out correct is not the reason the OP expected. Basically, you say that you can get the same value from a triangular region under the line $y=x$ as you can from a triangular region to the left of $y=x$, because the function $f: (x,y) \mapsto x^2 + y^2$ is symmetric about that line.

Answer (score 2):

If you examine carefully the values that $x$ and $y$ can take at any time during the integration, you should see that you always have $x\geq0$, $y\leq a$, and $y\geq x$.
That is, $(x,y)$ is always in the region bounded by the lines $x=0$, $y=a$,
and $y=x$ colored gray in the figure below:

[image]

There are some other conditions that are enforced by the bounds of integration,
in particular $x \leq a$, but we can see that this condition is redundant.
(All points in the triangular region already satisfy that condition.)

In other words, we're integrating values of $f$, but only the ones that are found
in that triangular region.

When you reverse the order of integration, you need to set the bounds of each integral
so that you still integrate only over the values of $(x,y)$ in the same triangle.
For one thing, you must ensure that $x \leq y$. That's where the upper bound of
the integral over $x$ comes from. The condition $x\geq 0$ gives the lower bound $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If function $[y>x]:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto 1$ if $y>x$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto0$ otherwise then: $$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{x}^{a}(x^2+y^2)dydx=$$$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}[y>x](x^2+y^2)dydx=\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}[y>x](x^2+y^2)dxdy=$$$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{y}(x^2+y^2)dxdy$$